# Getting attribute name (not attribute value) with Xpath

Tags: xpath

How would an Xpath expression look like that retrieves all attribute names (not attribute values!) for a given node resp. xml tag?

Assume the following XML document:

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="fr" type="easyreading">Monsieur Claude</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

The Xpath //title/@* would select "eng, fr, easyreading", but which Xpath would select "lang, lang, type"?

Comment: What version of XPath are you ussing? XPath 1.0 has no _sequence_ data type but it has a _node-set_ data type.

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try:

```
//@*/name()
```

returns

```
String='lang'
String='lang'
String='type'
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) regarding the name() function.